# Stuck on ControllerLinkBuilder

Tags: java, spring, url

I am currently trying to encode part of the URL but not all of it

Here is a sample of it:

```
http://localhost:8080/resourceSearch?type=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2FSSTG.owl%25252523Project&searchTerms={searchTerms}
```

For some reason it automatically encodes the last part with "searchTerms" whereas I want just the part prior to it to be encoded. The reason is because its a template URL that the client can replace the braces with the search term they want.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring, we create the urls with query parameters and path variables using `UriComponentsBuilder` as below

Path Variable:

```
UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
                .scheme("http")
                .host("http://localhost:8080/contextpath/")
                .path("/{variable1}/{variable2}/")
                .build()
                .expand("value1", "value2")
                .encode();
```

Query parameter

`.queryParam("value", "a")` for `http://localhost:8080/contextpath/?value=a`